# How to write SQL script to update conditional data and constraints?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, sql-update

I have just approached SQL and have not had the solution to do this.
I have 2 tables A and B:

```
A                B 
ID (char)        Year (char)
Zone (char)      Code (char)
ZCode (char)
```

At first, table B will be completely empty. Ex data of table A:

```
A                
01  A  2013/AA   
02  A  2018/KK
03  A  null
04  B  
05  B  2016/HH
```

I want to update data from table A to table B provided that only ZCode of Zone has the latest year and ZCode will be separated by a "/". This is the result I want:

```
B
2018  KK
2016  HH
```

Looking forward to having someone give me the solution to do this.

Comment: Is the specified Table B data before or after the operation? We want both versions.

Comment: At first, table B will be completely empty

Comment: If your data is consistent why cant u use `left-4` and `right-2`

Comment: Sorry can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution if your data is consistent. This only works if your data always have a complete year as number ex:`2018`on left and only 2 characters on right. This is more of hard coding of column length, cant see a reason why u cant use this.
Using `Max` will select latest year by code

```
Insert into tableB (Year,Code)
select Max(Left(Columnname,4)) year, 
       Right (columnname,2) Code  from TableA
       where Right (columnname,2) is not null or Right (columnname,2)<> ''
       group by Right (columnname,2)
```

Comment: Still 1 request from table A that is: just update when that ZCode not null and ZCode of Zone has the latest year

Comment: A slight change is done `Right (columnname,2)<> ''` instead of =

Comment: @TrietPham Please accept the answer if it solves your query

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableA')IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE TableA
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableB')IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE TableB
CREATE TABLE TableA (Id INT,Zone VARCHAR(2) ,ZCode VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE TableB ([Year] INT,Code VARCHAR(20))   
GO

INSERT INTO TableA(Id,Zone,ZCode)
SELECT 01,'A','2013/AA' UNION ALL   
SELECT 02,'B','2016/HH' UNION ALL
SELECT 03,'A','2018/KK' 
GO


INSERT INTO TableB

SELECT   [Year]
        ,[Code] 
FROM
(
    SELECT   SUBSTRING(ZCode,0,CHARINDEX('/',ZCode)) As [Year]
            ,SUBSTRING(ZCode,CHARINDEX('/',ZCode)+1,LEN(ZCode)) AS Code 
    FROM TableA
)dt


SELECT * FROM TableB  ORDER BY [Year] DESC
```

Result

```
Year    Code
------------
2018    KK
2016    HH
2013    AA
```

Comment: Still 1 request from table A that is: just update when that ZCode not null and ZCode of Zone has the latest year

Answer (score 1):

Below code snippet would give your desired output, now based on your requirement you can either do an `INSERT` into tableB or do an `UPDATE`

```
DECLARE @A TABLE(ID CHAR(10), ZONE CHAR(10), ZCODE CHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @A VALUES
('01',  'A',  '2013/AA'),   
('02',  'B',  '2016/HH'),
('03',  'A',  '2018/KK')

SELECT Year,Code FROM(
SELECT Year,Code,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ZONE ORDER BY Year DESC) rn FROM
(SELECT cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(ZCODE, '/', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[1]','varchar(100)') AS Year,
       cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(ZCODE, '/', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(100)') AS Code,*
FROM @A WHERE ZCODE IS NOT NULL) t1) t2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Still 1 request from table A that is: just update when that ZCode not null and ZCode of Zone has the latest year

Comment: Latest year condition will be taken care as the query is using `ROW_NUMBER()` to partition the data and get the latest year from it. Updated query will take care of ZCode null-ability too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to insert data into table B, when it is completely empty

```
INSERT INTO B ([YEAR], [MONTH])
select
Substring(ZCode,0,charindex('/',ZCode)) BYEAR,
Substring(ZCode,charindex('/',ZCode)+1,LEN(ZCode)-charindex('/',ZCode)) BCode
from A
```

else use can update this query to update record of  table B based on BCode.

Query edited for NOT NULL and GROUP condition

```
select MAX(v.BYEAR), v.BCode from
(select
 Substring(ZCode,0,charindex('/',ZCode)) BYEAR
,Substring(ZCode,charindex('/',ZCode)+1,LEN(ZCode)-charindex('/',ZCode)) BCode
from B ) v
Where v.BCODE IS NOT NULL 
Group by v.BCODE
```

Comment: Still 1 request from table A that is: just update when that ZCode not null and ZCode of Zone has the latest year

Comment: You can add group condition on BCode filed to get latest year.

Comment: select MAX(v.BYEAR), v.BCode from
(select
 Substring(ZCode,0,charindex('/',ZCode)) BYEAR
,Substring(ZCode,charindex('/',ZCode)+1,LEN(ZCode)-charindex('/',ZCode)) BCode
from B ) v
Where v.BCODE IS NOT NULL 
Group by v.BCODE

Answer (score 1):

In order to `UPDATE` in tableB you would required to `JOIN` the table with tableB on `Year / Code` columns

```
WITH CTE AS
(
     SELECT 
          left(a.zcode, 4) year, 
          substring(a.zcode, charindex('/', a.zcode)+1, len(a.zcode)) code  
     FROM tableA a
     INNER JOIN (
              select Zone, max(left(zcode, 4)) year 
              FROM tableA
              GROUP BY Zone
      )b ON a.Zone = b.zone and b.year = left(a.zcode, 4)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: Still 1 request from table A that is: just update when that ZCode not null and ZCode of Zone has the latest year